# Why Scipy is removing imread, imresize and other functions?

Tags: python, scipy

Today, when I was using scipy.misc.imread function I got the following warning:

```
/home/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:1: DeprecationWarning: `imread` is deprecated!
`imread` is deprecated in SciPy 1.0.0, and will be removed in 1.2.0.
Use ``imageio.imread`` instead.
  """Entry point for launching an IPython kernel.
```

I kind of find this disappointing. For me, this function was performing fine and I have used this in many codes. I come from the MATLAB community and this was a familiar function to me. Nevertheless, I became more disappointed after going to the [imageio imread documentation](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/userapi.html#imageio.imread):

```
imageio.imread(uri, format=None, **kwargs)
```

In the description, there is no indication what the `**kwargs` are. The full description is probably somewhere in the documentation. But I hope you guys get my point. Besides, this does not have the same functionality as the PIL one.

Comparing this to the [scipy imread documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.imread.html) or the [MATLAB imread documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imread.html) the documentation of imageio is just pointless.

That said, what are the reasons scipy is deprecating these functions?

Comment: It looks like they transitioned for the  following reason... https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scipy.html

Comment: Most of those functions have unexpected behavior (like rescaling and type casting image data without the user asking for that). Other functions simply have better alternatives.

Comment: That's understandable, although I never experienced these issues.